# Problema a la hora de correr un proyecto en Django

Tags: python, django, servidor

A la hora del aranque del servidor, el enlace de la url me sale que no existe el `templateDoesNotExist`, pero existe esta en una carpeta llamada directorio1

WEB:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/login/

admin/login.html

Request Method: GET Request URL: 127.0.0.1:8000 Django Version: 1.11 Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist Exception Value:

admin/login.html

Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in select_template, line 53 Python Executable: C:\Python27\python.exe Python Version: 2.7.14 Python Path:

['C:\Users\Marvin Bruno\eclipse-workspace\ProyectoFinalMesa22017', 'C:\Users\Marvin Bruno\eclipse-workspace\ProyectoFinalMesa22017', 'C:\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\Python27\lib', 'C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\Python27', 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-py2.7.egg', 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2017.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL', 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\python27.zip', 'C:\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools-38.2.4-py2.7.egg']

Server time: Wed, 20 Dec 2017 07:29:55 -0600
```

PROJECT: SETTINGS

```
import os

SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR, os.pardir)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(PROJECT_PATH)

TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates')
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'estatico')
DATABASE_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'directorio1.db')

# Printing paths for sanity's sake
print "Settings directory:", SETTINGS_DIR
print "Project root:", PROJECT_PATH
print "Templates:", TEMPLATE_PATH
print "estatico:", STATIC_PATH
print "DB:", DATABASE_PATH
LOGIN_URL = '/directorio1/login/'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)
MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': DATABASE_PATH,
    }
}

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'media')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/estatico/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    STATIC_PATH,
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
###SECRET_KEY = 'lzcpau%1br-$31x@ur+1@*uknf%((@qlb008_0oxo&kur&_92e'
SECRET_KEY = 'ht)zvye-87o8s)uexupd3k&)yo^+5xi5rm5f^^&_$yui-ia2sz'
# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',

#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ProyectoFinalMesa22017.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ProyectoFinalMesa22017.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    TEMPLATE_PATH,
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'directorio1',
)

SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

PROJECT: URLS

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
#from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
#from directorio1 import views 
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [

 #    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),  
     url(r'^directorio1/', include('directorio1.urls')), 
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Hola Marvin. Mira por favor [ask] y [tour]. Realmente no se entiende nada de tu pregunta y puede terminar cerrada. Una pared de codigo sin contexto no ayuda para nada. Podrias ser mucho mas claro?

Comment: el problema es que a la hora de correr el proyecto, tengo problema en el aranque de la url me sale que no existe el "templateDoesNotExist", pero existe esta en una carpeta llamada directorio1

Comment: sin entender de esto, primero usa el boton [edit] para dejar eso en claro en la pregunta. Elimina todo lo que no sea respecto a tu consulta puntual. y despues, no dice que lo esta buscando en /admin/login/?

Answer (score 0):

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
      os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, '<appname>/directorio1'),
)
```

Prueba con lo anterior (es decir sustituyelo en donde esta la variable TEMPLATE_DIRS) y donde esta  pones el nombre de tu aplicación o del módulo

Comment: es decir: 'ponElNombreDeTuAppAqui/directorio1'

Comment: HE TENIDO ERROR AL SUSTITUIR